# python add rows in dataframe based on a condition of another column

Tags: python, pandas

**What I have:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = ["version11.11","version2.2","version3"], columns=["software_version"])


  Index software_version
    0   version11.11
    1   version2.2
    2   version3
```

**What I am trying to do:**

Is to detect the type of the second last character in the dataframe column called `software_version` and create a new column in the dataframe based on that condition.

If the second last character is a digit or an alphabet, extract the whole name without the last alpha/digital. Such as `version11.11` becomes `version11.1` OR `version3` becomes `version`. elif, its a decimal place then extract til before the decimal place, `version2.2` becomes `version2`

**Output Should be:**

```
  Index software_version  main_software
    0   version11.11     version11.1
    1   version2.2       version2
    2   version3         version
```

**What I did so far:**

How can I cleanly add the column above `main_software` ?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = ["version11.11","version2.2","version3"], columns=["software_version"])

for name in df.software_version:
    if name[-2].isalnum():
        print(name[:-1])

    elif name[-2] == ".":
        print(name[:-2])

    else :
        print("!Alphanum-dot")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first define a function that makes the necessary changes on the string.

```
def GetMainSoftware(string):
    new_string=string[:-1] #first remove the last character
    if(new_string[-1]=="."): #if "." is present, remove that too
        return new_string[:-1]
    else:
        return new_string
```

And then use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on the dataframe to create a new column with these specifics.

```
df["main_software"]=df.apply(lambda row: GetMainSoftware(row["software_version"]),axis=1)
```

`df` will now be :

```
  software_version main_software
0     version11.11   version11.1
1       version2.2      version2
2         version3       version
```